# Issue Saving Offline-Filled HTML Form Data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I hope this message finds you well. I am working on a project that involves an HTML form designed to operate offline on my personal PC. The goal is to fill out this form offline mode on that means I want use this code html in no internet access area. I do not live in server or online website. I want only run my personal pc only. I have internet I do not use it. My problem solving in offline mode or run my pc only. and then save its content in HTML format when the user presses Ctrl + S. To achieve this, I have implemented a function that captures the form data and converts it into an HTML structure.
The objective is to fill out this form and then save its content in HTML format when I press Ctrl + S.

Here's the problem I'm encountering:

1. I fill out the form with data using various input fields and dropdowns.
2. I press Ctrl + S to save the data in HTML format.
3. However, the saved HTML file contains the structure of the form, but all the fields are empty.

I've explored several approaches to address this issue, but I have not succeeded in retaining the filled data when saving it in HTML format.

I would greatly appreciate your guidance on how to resolve this issue. If you have any insights, suggestions, or code examples that could help me ensure that the saved HTML file includes the filled data when working exclusively offline, I would be extremely grateful.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Best regards,
Prayas Kiran Sharma

1. I fill out the form with data using various input fields and dropdowns.
2. I press Ctrl     +      S to save the data in HTML format.
3. However, the saved HTML file contains the structure of the form, but all the fields are empty.

I've explored several approaches to address this issue, but I have not succeeded in retaining the filled data when saving it in HTML format.

```
 [https://jsfiddle.net/7espkiran/6qyv5fok/7/]
```